# add $email entry to email recipient

Tags: php, email

I'm using the following code from a contact form I've purchased;

```
$address = "myEmailAddress here";
$e_subject = 'Footie Tote from ' . $name . '.';
$e_body = "You have received scores from $name, with the following details;\n

Match A: $matcha\n
Match B: $matchb\n
Match C: $matchc\n
Match D: $matchd\n
Match E: $matche\n
Match F: $matchf\n
Match G: $matchg\n
Match H: $matchh\n

Name: $name\n

Email: $email\n

" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );
$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {  etc.
```

I'm trying to also have the email sent to another email address, which is the email address someone has entered into the form (the $email value), so it's like they are getting a copy of the submitted form.

Could someone please point me in the right direction to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, these worked by adding the CC/BCC of $email. Apologies for breaking the rules of asking... I will include my workings next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at [the examples in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), it looks like you can just add `CC` headers (or `BCC` if you prefer).  Specifically looking at the headers in Example #4 on that page, you should be able to just do something like this:

```
// ... previous code
$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "CC: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
// ... later code
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a bcc:

```
$headers .= "Bcc: $email" . PHP_EOL;
```

Just add that beneath the from line and it should send a blind copy to $email

Bcc makes it so the user is not notified of the copy. As David said, CC would also work. It would just include the cc email plainly to the user.